# Java .length equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I change this code snippet so it runs the length of the array? The type of data in the array is a `Mat` from OpenCV.

```
for (int i = 0; i < subImages.length(); i++) {
    UIImage *subImage = [self UIImageFromMat:subImages[i]];
    [_subImgs addObject:subImage];
}
```

I get an error on `subImages.length();`

Comment: Why would you assume that what works in Java works in C++ as well? (is it a raw array? if so, use `sizeof subImages / sizeof sumImages[0]`.)

Comment: I did not assume it would work in C++, its just a way or demonstrating what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function template for this:

```
#include <cstddef> // for std::size_t

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size(T (&)[N])
{
  return N;
}
```

Usage:

```
Foo foos[42];
std::cout << size(foos) << std::endl;
```

Note that this only works for fixed size arrays, like the `sizeof` based methods. It will not work in a context where the array has decayed into a pointer, or with pointers to dynamically allocated arrays. If you need dynamic arrays, opt for `std::vector` instead. This has a `size()` method:

```
std::vector<Foo> v(42); // v contains 42 Foo objects
std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: My array is dynamically allocated, this is unsafe to use correct?

Comment: @Nick Yes, because all you have is a pointer to that array. All size information is lost. But you can use an`std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(datatype)
```

Comment: better use `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]` for safety.

Comment: My array is dynamically allocated, is this safe?

Comment: @Nick No, it doesn't even work in that case. If you want dynamically allocated arrays, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Be aware of the [The Null Packet](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6592) , you don't want to divide by 0 and melt your CPU. Just saying :)